# Instantiating a generic type with an overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, oop

```
class MyClass<T> where T: new()
{
    public Test()
    {
        var t = new T();
        var t = new T("blah"); // <- How to do this?
    }
}
```

I know that's not possible as written, and as far as I understand it's just simply not allowed (although I would love nothing more than to be wrong about that).  The first solution that comes to mind is to use an object initializer, but let's suppose that's a last resort because it would conflict with other oop goals in this case.

My next inclination would be to use reflection, but before I do that I'd like to know if I am overlooking any easier way to do this or perhaps a different design pattern that would work better?

Comment: I would say Reflection is your only hope. But with reflection you have to rely on convention rather than the compile time checking which probably is what you're looking for. Maybe you could use a Factory perhaps, but I can't see how a Factory could be generic and still do the job. 
Object initialization != OOP.

Comment: I would agree with @MikaelÖstberg and go for using a factory.

Comment: But could the Factory be generic? I would face the very same challenges as what we see in the code now. The Factories would have to be concrete.

Comment: Yeh that is true, but the factory would be able to abstract away the concrete type of T. So there would be a concrete factory with multiple overloads to create T in different ways or maybe even derived classes of T

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a BusinessObjectsBase and BusinessObjectBase that use dynamic parameterized sql to do all the CRUD.  So far it's looking very promising and like a lot less overhead than using an ORM while still being more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly. You'll need to use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx), but doing so has all the drawbacks of reflection, meaning that you miss out on compile-time checking etc.

```
public Test()
{
    var t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), (object)"blah");
}
```

Comment: Sweet, I think that's my best option.  I've used that in the past and I kept thinking I could do something like that in the back of my mind but for whatever reason I had just forgotten about it and was thinking reflection was going to require some convoluted hard to read/maintain code.  This is simple enough though.

Answer (score 3):

You can force user to give you the way to construct the object from `string`, like this:

```
internal class MyClass<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public void Test(Func<string, T> func)
    {
        var t = func("blah");
    }
}
```

`Function` can be part of contruction `MyClass` object, so you won't have to pass it each time you call methods that have to create `T`. Actually with that aproach `new()` might not be needed.

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting.  I'm going with the Activator.CreateInstance solution for now but if reflection performance is less than desired I may just look into trying this.